Global namespace changes depending on scope?
I have the following function defined in my Spyder startup file:
# startup.py
#-----------
def del_globals(*names):
   for name1 in names:
      try: del globals()[name1]
      except KeyError: pass # Ignore if name1 doesn't exist

At the Spyder console, I run the following script with the debugger to create a variable cat before descending into a function:
# MyScript.py
#------------
runfile('The/Path/to/startup.py') # In case functions are deleted
cat='dog'
del_globals('cat')

I have a breakpoint at the last line del_globals('cat').  Upon breaking, I confirm that cat is a variable in the global namespace:
sorted(globals().keys())
# ['TKraiseCFG', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__',
#  '__loader__', '__name__', '__nonzero__', '__package__',
#  '__spec__', 'cat', 'del_globals']

I then step into del_globals('cat') and at the very first line (the for statement), confirmed that cat is not in the global namespace
sorted(globals().keys())
['TKraiseCFG', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__',
 '__name__', '__nonzero__', '__package__', '__spec__',
 '_spyderpdb_builtins_locals', '_spyderpdb_code',
 '_spyderpdb_locals', 'del_globals']

Should there be just one global namespace, and should that be the prevailing namespace at the REPL command line?
P.S. For background, the context is described here and here.

Related: Visibility of global variables in imported modules, What is a module variable vs. a global variable? See also: Short description of the scoping rules

you should just pass in globals() to your function from the caller, i.e. the signature should be def del_globals(globals, *names) then the code should just globals.pop(name, None), and the caller should do something like del_globals(globals(), 'foo', 'bar', 'baz')

@jasonharper yes, and it is exactly my_module.__dict__

@wjandrea: Thanks for the links.  I just spent the evening romping through those topics online (before I saw your comment).

@juanpa_arrivillaga: The more code, identifiers, and punctuation needed to invoke the deleter, the more noise it introduces into the main body of code.  To me, it's worth it to see if it can be done without passing in globals(), but I know that's a fallback plan.  Thanks.

Thanks, @jasonharper.  Sometimes, I upvote comments without an explicit thank you, making me seem like a thankless question poser.

globals in Python are really per module.
So, the call to globals() inside startup.py file will return you the global variables defined in that file (which will include the del_globals function itself.
What Spyder is doing is injecting all function definitions from startup.py in the global namespace of the module used interactiely at the console. This injection is equivalent to what one gets in statements like from startup import del_globals: a reference to the function in the other module is bound to the current module globals with the same name. But the function object itself is bound to the global variables from that module - it is easy to introspect this, they are bound to the __globals__ attribute of the function itself:
import startup
from startup import del_globals

del_globals.__globals__ is startup.__dict__
# should return True

The fix for this is possible, but requires advancing on Python introspection capabilities: a function can "know" the running environment from where it was called by introspecting Frame objects  - these are runtime objects that bind together various stateful attributes needed to run any python code - and form a stack, one frame pointing to the one that preceded it in its .f_back attribute - and they also contain a reference to their own "globals" namespace.
All that said, this should work as you intend:
import inspect

def del_globals(*names):
   caller_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
   caller_globals = caller_frame.f_globals
   for name1 in names:
      try: del caller_globals[name1]
      except KeyError: pass # Ignore if name1 doesn't exist



Can you link to the runfile documentation? I'm having trouble finding it.

Alternatively, they could do one "setup" call to pass the correct globals, and then del_globals could use that. Or like a factory, set up with del_globals = get_del_globals(globals()).

@jsbueno: Thanks.  I'm going to give it a try tomorrow.  However, since you're reaching back to the frame of the caller, I wonder if it makes sense to del variables from the caller's local scope (which would be the same as the global scope if del_globals() is called from the REPL prompt).  I read that removing items from the caller's locals() dictionary doesn't unbind the variable, so instead, I searched for whether del can be made to do this, e.g., reading this.  It doesn't seem so.

I will try to plumb the inspect documentation to see if I can do something like try: del caller_locals[name1].

@no comment: I'm relatively new to Python and not a developer.  Would you be able to explain your code pattern del_globals = get_del_globals(globals())?

@user2153235 the thing about "changing locals()" not binding variables only works when locals() refers to  function scope. At module level, which includes a REPL environment, locals() returns the same object as globals(), which is a plain dicitionary, and effecting it is the same than changing the variable bindings with the = operator.

what you comment bellow,  affecting caller´s locals, if they are in fact local to a function scope, would not work (not without advancing one or two extra layers in the introspection machinery).

@jsbueno: OK, I think I see.  Your use of caller_globals works because globals are visible across frames but locals are not.  I do understand that the global namespace is implemented as a dictionary, which is why we can manipulate globals() to affect that namespace, whereas locals() is merely a reflection of the local namespace/scope, which is why manipulating locals() won't necessarily impact the local namespace/scope.  I hope I didn't butcher that up description.

@jsbueno: Your code works great.  Thanks!
